# regex specific character inside string

Tags: regex

I was trying to find solution, but couldn't. 
What will be regex when I have a string of defined length (let's say 10), and one of characters have to be specific letter (let's say 'd').

My first idea was something like this:

```
^([0-9d]{10})$
```

But it allows multiple 'd' in string, and I want exactly one.

Answer (score 4):

You may use

```
^(?=.{10}$)[0-9]*d[0-9]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CYDwyT/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{10}$)` - any 10 chars (other than a newline) followed with the end of string (you may precise this part if you wish, `(?=[0-9d]{10}$)`)
- `[0-9]*` - 0+ digits
- `d` - a `d`
- `[0-9]*` - 0+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: wow, that's pretty clever.  I was trying to use negative look aheads for _not_ d